# Updating list value in Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion

thanks for reading! I have created a recursive sudoku solving program that (among other things)calls a function "step" that adds elements to all positions on the board which only have one possible solution in that elements set of solutions. This is done through the following:

```
sudoku.grid.updated(row, sudoku.grid(row).updated(column, value))
```

Where row, column and value are tuples being returned from an above function, And sudoku is another class and grid is a:

```
val grid: List[List[Int]]
```

Where each row takes a new List.When I print the above code segment i correctly get an updated List, for eg.

```
List(6, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 9, 3)
```

becomes

```
List(6, 0, 0, 4, 1, 8<<<Correctly Updated, 0, 9, 3)
```

as needed, but when it comes to printing the whole grid by simply removing the print() from the first code segment, the values do not update. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you assigning the updated grid to anything? Or just passing it to the print function? You might want to show a bit more of the code context for the problem to become clear.

Comment: Please show your code so that someone can reproduce it. 

Provide a runnable example so that it's easy for folks to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.List` is immutable (good thing), you cannot change its content. `List.updated` returns a *new* list with the elements changed as specified, that's what you see when you print the value returned from your code. But the original list is not modified.

A way around this would be to use `scala.collection.mutable.Seq` instead of `List`. These are mutable collections, on which you can call `seq.update(index, elem)`, and that will change the content of the actual underlying collection.

Better yet, figure out away to do what you need with only (or mostly) immutable objects. This is the functional way.